# Cannot resolve fontawesome dependencies IntelliJ Project - missing pom

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, dependencies, font-awesome

I am starting to loose my sanity here...

I have a Java Project in IntelliJ IDE, it needs to have JavaFX so newer versions fail:

IntelliJ IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.8538.31, built on July 7, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_231-b11 amd64
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0

Project SDK: Java 1.8

Maven: Bundled Maven 3 (Maven 3.6.3)

Now my project needs some fontawesome dependencies but all versions I need are no longer in Maven central so I added them manually to my .m2 repository (including all things like source files, doc file, pom etx). Now there is no more error in the code but as soon as I try to reimport all maven repositories it gives me the error that none of the dependencies could be resolved.

[image]

additionally when I open the maven overview and check the dependencies, there are even the wrong references still in the list (the newer ones I tried but did not work with my software version).

I want for example commons 8.15 but it also shows commons 9.1.2 which I tried earlier.

[image]

finally when I try to clean install the project it gives me the error that the pom files for the fontawesome dependencies are missing. But they are in the folders I created.

[image]
[image]

There must be something I am missing out here. It gets all the Information it needs. If I open the project structure libraries they are all there and fine. It is working on my colleques laptops and after hours I still can't find any difference to my setup. Is is really the "missing" pom files (which are there) or did I mess up the connection?
Any hint would be helpful!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
So the first time I simply added the folders to the .m2 directory and changed the dependency section to take the old versions. Now tried something else, I loaded each dependency extra into the library via project structure (with structure and doc info). And I also removed the corresponding dependeny section of the pom. Now the Maven reimport works without error and the code is also errorless. But as soon as I try clean install the project it fails on install saying the packages don't exist.

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.emojione.EmojiOne;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.emojione.EmojiOneView;
```

Import statements give no error but the classes error when building... Do I use them wrong now that the import is from an external lib and no dependency section is there to call?

When I add the dependency section again it can not resolve them at all. I looked at the link from the comment and this is how one of this dependencies looks:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-commons</artifactId>
            <version>8.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

but I don't know why it can't resolve or find it... it is there. I checked for each module that it is listed as dependency in the project structure, I also tried to invalidate the caches manually...

So I think my main question is: How do I connect the dependency section with the code. Is the import statement changing? Is the static classic import the right way to do it? Is it ok the libs are lokated in the .m2 diectory?

Comment: Looks like you are using Java 8, but some of Fontawesome jars look like they are for Java 9+. Just my guess.

Comment: the newer versions were for Java 9+ but the ones I want to use (the old ones) should work just fine with Java8 we used them for at least 2 years now. But when I try to make it run on my laptop it wont work..

Comment: Did you make sure the pom only had the resources you need? If so, try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: does it matter if I include the libraries that are already in the .m2 directory? is the groupID or something else wrong in case I include it manually? There is a pom file with some of the dependencies but they all say the same things I use in <dependency> part.